# Problems with custom module installation

Tags: openerp-7

I am new to OpenERP, Python and PostgreSQL and I'm trying to create a custom module in OpenERP 7.

I have looked around over the Internet but cannot find a step by step guide on

> how to create and install a custom module in OpenERP?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: have you problem with custom module installation or you don't know how to make new module in OpenERP? Because your question title tell else and your question description.

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation step just follow the below Link**

[Click to Guide Steps By Steps Module implementation](http://openerp-web-v7.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module.html)

**Reference link provide the implementation Stuff which is used to implement the Module in OpenERP 7.0**

[Follow the  Ref.Stuff for OpenERP 7.0](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-i-can-create-module-openerp-7-16336)

I hope this will helpful for you